# The term 'X' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I found [this script](http://poshcode.org/2123) that will loop through .csv files and combine them into one Excel worksheet. I then created a second script to call this one with the following:

```
echo "Combining .csv files into Excel workbook"
C:\PowerShell\ConvertCSVtoExcel.ps1
Get-ChildItem *.csv | ConvertCSV-ToExcel -output ePortalMontlyReport.xlsx
echo " "
```

But when I try to run the script, I am getting the following error:

```
ConvertCSV-ToExcel : The term 'ConvertCSV-ToExcel' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\PowerShell\Merge.ps1:3 char:23
+ Get-ChildItem *.csv | ConvertCSV-ToExcel -output ePortalMontlyReport. ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertCSV-ToExcel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to dot-source the .ps1 file to get the functions in it imported into your session.

```
. C:\PowerShell\ConvertCSVtoExcel.ps1
```

Comment: The documentation for the dot source operator can be found in `Get-Help about_Operators`.  Not that there's a whole lot there, but that's where it's listed.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx (about_Scripts) and http://ss64.com/ps/source.html can help, too ^_^

Comment: Thanks - that moved me past this particular error and on to the next one - but at least I was able to advance.